# Troubles parsing XML object in PHP (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml, laravel-5.8

I'm having troubles parsing an XML object in PHP. I'm using Laravel 5.8

Here is one of my tries:

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($formatted, LIBXML_BIGLINES);

var_dump($xml->children('soapenv', true)->Envalop->Body->children('ns3', true)->getAddressBookResponse->addressBook[0]->businessUnit);
```

And I'm getting the following error:

`Call to a member function children() on null`

I have tried different variations of creating and accessing the `SimpleXMLElement` but always with the same result. I'm getting back an empty object of type`SimpleXMLElement`

Here is a sample XML that I'm using as input (coming from SOAP API call):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns3:getAddressBookResponse xmlns:ns2="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JPRCUST0/" 
            xmlns:ns3="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JPR01000/">
            <e1MessageList>
                <e1Messages>
                    <message>Description:  All records for the query have not been returned.
                    </message>
                </e1Messages>
            </e1MessageList>
            <addressBook>
                <businessUnit>123456</businessUnit>
                <categoryCodesAddressBook>
                    <categoryCode001>XXX</categoryCode001>
                    <categoryCode002>XXX</categoryCode002>
                </categoryCodesAddressBook>
                <description1>MOHAMEDHASSANALI</description1>
            </addressBook>
            <addressBook>
                <businessUnit>789789</businessUnit>
                <categoryCodesAddressBook>
                    <categoryCode001>YYY</categoryCode001>
                    <categoryCode002>YYY</categoryCode002>
                </categoryCodesAddressBook>
                <description1>ALIHASSANAHMED</description1>
            </addressBook>
        </ns3:getAddressBookResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You can check this link if  you want to get children information of xml using core function of PHP. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-simplexmlelement-children-function/

Comment: @BhavinThummar My problem is in creating the XML object, not accessing it. I'm getting back an empty object. Thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: Please check below link https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php
I think it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not just XML, but SOAP. I suggest using a SOAP library (like ext/soap).

It's `Envelope` not `Envalop`. And this is the element in you `$xml` variable.

If you want to treat it as just XML, do not rely on the namespaces prefixes but the actual namespace URIs (the values of the xmlns attributes). Prefixes can change. A prefix like `ns3` is auto generated by a SOAP library, just adding/removing an element with another namespace could change it. So define constants or variables for the XMLNS values and use them.

```
const XMLNS_SOAP = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
const XMLNS_ADDRESSES = 'http://oracle.e1.bssv.JPR01000/';

$envelope = new \SimpleXMLElement($formatted, LIBXML_BIGLINES);

var_dump(
  $envelope->children(XMLNS_SOAP)->Body->children(XMLNS_ADDRESSES)->getAddressBookResponse->children('')->addressBook[0]->businessUnit
);
```

Xpath expressions (`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`) allow for conditional fetching. This avoids problems if an element is missing, but you will have to register your own prefixes for the namespaces.

```
const XMLNS_SOAP = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
const XMLNS_ADDRESSES = 'http://oracle.e1.bssv.JPR01000/';

$envelope = new \SimpleXMLElement($formatted, LIBXML_BIGLINES);
$envelope->registerXpathNamespace('s', XMLNS_SOAP);
$envelope->registerXpathNamespace('a', XMLNS_ADDRESSES);

var_dump(
  $envelope->xpath('(s:Body/a:getAddressBookResponse/addressBook)[1]/businessUnit')
);
```